# Retreive list elements using pnp search in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is this the right way to retreive list elements using pnp search in Sharepoint

```
 pnp.sp.search("ListName").then((r: SearchResults) => {
        console.log(r.ElapsedTime);
        console.log(r.RowCount);
        console.log(r.PrimarySearchResults);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search is accessed directly from the root sp object and can take either a string representing the query text, a plain object matching the `SearchQuery` interface, or a `SearchQueryBuilder` instance. The first two are shown below.

```
import pnp, { SearchQuery, SearchResults } from "sp-pnp-js";

// text search using SharePoint default values for other parameters
pnp.sp.search("test").then((r: SearchResults) => {

    console.log(r.ElapsedTime);
    console.log(r.RowCount);
    console.log(r.PrimarySearchResults);
});

// define a search query object matching the SearchQuery interface
pnp.sp.search(<SearchQuery>{
    Querytext: "test",
    RowLimit: 10,
    EnableInterleaving: true,
}).then((r: SearchResults) => {

    console.log(r.ElapsedTime);
    console.log(r.RowCount);
    console.log(r.PrimarySearchResults);
});
```

Searching for Office 365 groups. To ensure you are searching all groups in Office 365 please see the example below, which includes the "`EnableDynamicGroups`" property.

```
import pnp, { SearchQueryBuilder, SearchResults, SearchQuery } from "sp-pnp-js";

const _searchQuerySettings: SearchQuery = {
    TrimDuplicates: false,
    RowLimit: 500,
    SelectProperties: ["Title", "SPWebUrl", "projectID"],
    Properties: [{
      Name: "EnableDynamicGroups",
      Value: {
        BoolVal: true,
        QueryPropertyValueTypeIndex: 3
      }
    }]
}

let q = SearchQueryBuilder.create("ContentType:ProsjektInformasjon", _searchQuerySettings).rowLimit(500);

pnp.sp.search(q).then(res => { 
    console.log(res.PrimarySearchResults.length);
    console.dir(res.PrimarySearchResults)
});
```